# Lipschitz domain and surface measure

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

Let $S$ be the boundary of a Lipschitz domain $\Omega$. We know it has a surface measure $\mu$. Can we write $d\mu = f(x)dx$ with $f$ explicity given in terms of the Lipschitz maps that make up the domain $\Omega$ (or any other form)?

Where can I learn more about this surface measure??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is $f(x) = \sqrt{1+|\nabla h|^2}$ on any portion of the surface that is represented by $x_k = h(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)$.  By Rademacher's Theorem, a Lipschitz map on $\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable almost everywhere.  And $|\nabla h|$ will be bounded by the Lipschitz constant of $h$, so there is no problem seeing that $f$ is bounded.